# How do I write ampscript to direct different members to different links?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

I'm new to Marketing Cloud and we have segmented audience that receives the same email, but will be directed to different links.

How do I write ampscript to say: If you see BV=Corporate in the data, then the link in this sentence should be x; when BV=Retail, then the link should be y.

I'm sure this is very simple, but I don't know where to put it in the code, or how to write it.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend going through some related materials about amp script, such as The Ampscript Guide (https://ampscript.guide/), which is a popular guide to learn SFMC native scripting language. I would be really careful about using amp script without a proper understanding of it.

To answer your question. If you have just a few links, you can create something like this:

```
%%[
VAR @BV, @redirectURL
SET @BV = AttributeValue("BV_Attribute")

IF @BV == "Corporate" THEN
  SET @redirectURL = "https://xyz.com/abc"
ELSE 
  SET @redirectURL = "https://xyz.com/efg"
ENDIF
]%%
```

In your email, you will use the following inline AMPscript to populate the URL address:

```
%%=v(@redirectURL)=%%
```

This is just a super simple version. Of course, you can have more conditions and a default condition as well (see https://ampscript.guide/statements/).

If you have a lot of links, I suggest you have them in the data extension you use for sending. You would prepare it via SQL (Automation Studio), where you could use CASE statements to determine the proper URL per subscriber. You will use that DE for sending. This time, you will use the AttributeValue function to get directly the URL from the DE.

Comment: thank you much for this! I'll give it a try

Comment: I tried this script and I get an error message that says: An IF statement is not closed with the required ENDIF statement. I have used your code above which does have an ENDIF statement so not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Hello @IsabellaLynch can you try it now? I have not tested it out on my side. I edited the post. Now it should work without issues. If this helped, please don’t forget to accept my answer.

Comment: Hi there, the script worked, but now the issue is that only one of the redirect emails work, and the other gets an error message

Comment: when I click on the link, the link tries to redirect to %%=v(@redirectURL)=%%, but the ELSE set redirect link to seems to work with no issue.

Comment: HI there, is there an update to this as I would really like to get the ampscript working. Not sure why one link works and the other links gets an error. the URLs are definitely correct.

Comment: Hello @IsabellaLynch, it is working on my side. No issues. Just be aware, that with my advice, I am not able to provide you with a full solution. I really don’t know how your code looks like, whether there are non amp-script related issues or not. Of course, that the inline ampscript (%%=v(@redirectURL)=%%), cannot be a standalone copy paste into your content editor. Instead, you should paste into the HTML editor the following code:
<div>
  <a href="%%=v(@redirectURL)=%%">Test URL</a></div>